# URL to controller/action in external Javascript file

Tags: jquery, grails-2.0

I have a form that handles editing of a domain model (A). This domain model also `hasMany` other domain models (B). So in order to add new Bs to A, I wanted to implement a custom AJAX function, that sends the parameters of some input fields to the controller.

In order to do so, I've created the following GSP:

```
<g:form>
<!-- other stuff concerning entity A -->
    <p>Add B to A</p>
    <input type="text" id="bName" /> <input type="text" id="bSomeProperty" <a href="#" id="addB">Add</a>
</g:form>
```

And added the following piece of Javascript to my `main.js` that is loaded by the `resources` plugin.

```
$("#addB").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '', // controller: a, action: addB
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            bName: $('#bName').val(),
            bSomeProperty: $('#bSomeProperty').val(),
        }
    });
});
```

So, the question is: How can I retrieve the URL that points to the current controller and action `addB`? I don't want to hard-code it or use a relative path, if possible - since Grails actually provides some methods to retrieve the link.

Using the `remoteFunction` in Javascript did not work for me, since I use jQuery. Both don't seem to work well together.

I also found this blog article (http://alexduan.com/2011/02/17/grails-jquery-and-ajax/) about Grails, jQuery and AJAX. He uses a variable within the javascript part. Unfortunately, the `contextPath` variable isn't parsed, since the Javascript is not within the GSP page but in an external file.

What can I do?

Options:

- Put the Javascript piece in a `g:javascript` tag within the page (somewhat ugly, because it's somewhat inline)
- Use a relative URL (not very robust)
- Get the `remoteFunction` to work (how to do with jQuery?)
- anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use your first option in my projects: I load a subset of all my mapping in a global myapp.urls javascript object, such that

```
myapp.urls['mappingName'] = url
```

2 problems arise:

- you have to select the urls you want to expose since they become public
- web crawls (GoogleBot for instance) will follow these links if you did not craft a robots.txt for this.

So to enhance this solution I base64-encoded the inline call so I get something looking like this:

```
myapp.urls=eval(base64_decode('gYW55IGNhcm5hbCBwbGVhc3VyZS4=='));
```

It's not perfect but it works.

Comment: Thanks! I added a global variable to my `main.gsp` so I can access the `contextPath` in every other Javascript file and build the path to controller and action myself.